# Angularjs filter with custom function from controller

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to filter a table based on age with conditions as less than and greater than 25 years.

[Here is the demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kg2kscnw/9/)

The filtering function is not happening as expected. For less than 25 it returns no results and for greater than 25 it returns 44 and 25.

Kindly let me know how to get the results correct?

```
vm.filterByAgeFn = function(subject){
    filterReturn = true;

    if(vm.filterByAge){

        switch(vm.filterByAge){
        case '<25':
            if(parseInt(subject.age) >= 25){
            filterReturn = false}

        case '>25':
            if(parseInt(subject.age) < 25){
            filterReturn = false}

      }
    }

    return filterReturn;
  }
```

Comment: I got the task completed in https://jsfiddle.net/kg2kscnw/10/. But need to know why the above code didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Why are your less than and greater than backwards?

The less than and greater than in the switch doesn't match the string case not to mention I'm not sure that strong case is a real good idea.  I would use and object to hold the key for less than and greater than.